# ansible: filtering the content of a variable with regex

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to write an ansible role to automate installing julia programming language in arch linux enviroment. Unfortunately, because of llvm, arch linux advises not to use delivered by package manager.

My playbook receives the version information from command line with extra-var which is represented as target_version variable. Following task which is part of a role gives an error stating that major_version is not defined that is derived from target_version by filtering target_version with regex.  target_version is something similar to a string as 1.8.2. I am trying to capture the initial 1.8 part of the version string to create the url.  Assume the conditions on
julia_installed_version and target_version hold true. I have marked the offending part of the code

```
- name: Check if install is needed
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
     install_needed: true
     # FOLLOWING LINE CREATES ERROR
     major_version: "{{ target_version | regex_search('\\d+\\.\\d+')}}" 
     tar_file_name: "julia-{{ target_version }}-linux-x86_64.tar.gz"  
     download_url: "https://julialang-s3.julialang.org/bin/linux/x64/{{ major_version }}/{{ tar_file_name }}" 
  when: julia_installed_version is defined  and  target_version is version(julia_installed_version.stdout, '>')
```

I wrote a tiny test code, the marked line works if target_version is a string, but gives error if it is variable. I really do not know what is going on. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to separate the definition of the fact:

```
- name: Check if installed needed
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
     install_needed: true
     major_version: "{{ target_version | regex_search('\\d+\\.\\d+')}}" 
     tar_file_name: "julia-{{ target_version }}-linux-x86_64.tar.gz"
  when:
    - julia_installed_version is defined
    - target_version is version(julia_installed_version.stdout, '>') 

- name: Assign download URL
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
     download_url: "https://julialang-s3.julialang.org/bin/linux/x64/{{ major_version }}/{{ tar_file_name }}" 
  when:
    - julia_installed_version is defined
    - major_version is defined
    - tar_file_name is defined
```

A way to understand it is that all the templates of the `set_fact` happen at the same time, the template of `download_url` assumes that the values for `major_version` and `tar_file_name` have been already assigned.

Comment: also note that the list of  the `when` operation, each item will be evaluated with an `and` logical operator, splitting them makes it easier to read

Comment: Thank you, just after posting, I realized that facts can not referenced in the same tasks where they are defined. I marked your answer as the solution.